# Trying to understand my Full Text search result

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

I run sql server 2012 and applied FTS index on a 800K rows table. 
The table was filled with arbitrary data in rows.
I use [irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) to parse my user defined text and then I search the following text "

```
Zaphod gave him
```

Which I know I have in the db since I run the following sql

```
declare @searchterm nvarchar(max) = '%Zaphod gave him%'

select fact.id,<MyColumns>
from [dbo].[fact] as fact
where MyColumnAName like @searchterm or
      MyColumnBName like @searchterm 
      ....
```

The Irony engine generates the following statement

```
 (( FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Zaphod)  AND
    FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, gave) ) AND  
    FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, him) )
```

and I add it to an sql

```
SELECT fact.id, KEY_TBL.RANK, <MyColumns>
FROM [dbo].[Fact] as fact
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(fact,*, '(( FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Zaphod)  AND  
                                     FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, gave) ) AND  
                                     FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, him) )') AS KEY_TBL
ON fact.ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
ORDER BY RANK DESC
```

Now one row that has the exact text twice - in two different rows is located after many rows that has this exact figure once.
They all get the same rank.
Can I set  this row earlier in the result set?
Is that sorted like that because the rank is not precised enough?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx), FREETEXTTABLE does not support FORMSOF.

FREETEXTTABLE already matches inflectional forms of your words as well as synonyms (see the [FREETEXT documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) for more info). FREETEXT/FREETEXTTABLE also do not support operators, so depending on what's in your stop list it may be matching the word "AND" too. (It will also look for the words "FORMSOF" and "INFLECTIONAL" but they are likely not in your index. But that won't affect your search since FREETEXT/FREETEXTTABLE only need to match at least 1 word in your search string.)

FORMSOF is only supported by CONTAINS and CONTAINSTABLE.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. That was a bit hidden in the documentation. 
To test if you are correct I have just queried FREETEXTTABLE(fact,*, 'Zaphod') and FREETEXTTABLE(fact,*, '(FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, Zaphod)'). the Count(*) was the same. the rank was much higer in the first query. Seems you are right :-).